# Kendo Angular 2 npm Install Error in VSTS for @progress

Tags: angular, npm-install, kendo-ui-angular2, azure-pipelines-build-task

Our project is currently hosted on Visual Studio Team Services and built on premises using a build agent.  Our build step which installs npm packages is currently failing.  All regular npm packages are being loaded  and installed correctly it is just the Kendo private repository packages in the @progress scope.  I have run the command below on the server with the build agent and I can list versions of packaged but it has had no effect on the build step.

```
npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress
```

Build step error below...

> 2017-01-10T11:07:21.9674570Z [command]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
>   install 2017-01-10T11:07:29.2981900Z npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   2017-01-10T11:07:29.2991901Z npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   2017-01-10T11:07:29.2991901Z npm ERR! node v6.9.4
>   2017-01-10T11:07:29.2991901Z npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>   2017-01-10T11:07:29.2991901Z npm ERR! code E404
>   2017-01-10T11:07:29.3011903Z  2017-01-10T11:07:29.3031905Z npm ERR!
>   404 Not found : @progress/kendo-data-query
>   2017-01-10T11:07:29.3041906Z npm ERR! 404 
>   2017-01-10T11:07:29.3051907Z npm ERR! 404 
>   '@progress/kendo-data-query' is not in the npm registry.
>   2017-01-10T11:07:29.3081910Z npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to
>   publish it (or use the name yourself!) 2017-01-10T11:07:29.3081910Z
>   npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'angular2-quickstart'
>   2017-01-10T11:07:29.3101912Z npm ERR! 404 
>   2017-01-10T11:07:29.3101912Z npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also
>   install from a 2017-01-10T11:07:29.3101912Z npm ERR! 404 tarball,
>   folder, http url, or git url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you've executed the login command with the same user that runs the build.

You can also include a per-project `.npmrc` file, see the [VSTS documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/npm/npmrc).

The `.npmrc` file should contain at least these lines:

```
@progress:registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/
//registry.npm.telerik.com/:_authToken=[secret token here]
```

Comment: Thanks Tsvetomir changing the account of the service to match the account that ran the login command worked!

Comment: hi! can you tell me how to get [secret token here] value for my subscription? thank you!

Comment: The token will be available in your ~/.npmrc file once you execute `npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress`